# Accessing UITextView from another class

Tags: uitextview, viewcontroller

I've currently got two view controllers A and B, A uses a segue to push B and this works back and forth  nicely, however based on some button presses in view controller B i want to change the text within a UITextView in controller A.

I've had a look at previous posts but i'm a novice at present and was confused by the way in which i should go about doing this.

I'd love to be able to get my head around how interactions are best done between various parts of the app. Also i was wondering if there is a way i can tap into a segue returning to trigger some other code.

Thanks

Edit:
OK perhaps i was a little bit limited with my information, from what i can gather reading other posts they are manually creating a variable for the viewcontroller (A)  in viewcontroller (B) then accessing it in the second view controller (B) and setting a variable (property and synthesize) to edit that way, however i have the viewcontrollers embedded in a navigation controller and using a push setup in the storyboard (GUI system). I'm not sure if i have to create a variable to do this or if because they exist in the storyboard there is another way, if someone could just point me in the direction of a post that helps to explain this (i am looking at the moment too) i'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well here's how i got it to work but i imagine there are:

A: Better ways to do it.
B: Changes depending on your setup.

I had my two view controllers embedded in a navigation controller, and used a segue push to access the second view controller each had a different class (all setup in the storyboard thing).

To get it working for me i did the following:

I have a singleton (a class that stores all my data but is global to the app so the variables can be accessed from anywhere in the app) this allows me to have variables that i can access from any view controller. A great tutorial on this can be found [here](http://sree.cc/iphone/global-functions-and-variables-in-objective-c)

I then created an NSString variable (passedNote) and updated the value of this variable from the ViewController B, when my button was pressed.

Next when viewController A  is loaded (in the viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated method) i append or replace the value of the textview (dependent on some logic) I have with the global variable (passedNote).

Hope this helps anyone who had the problem.